# ¿Cómo obtener la duracion de un MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, mediaplayer

Estoy creando un reproductor de música y necesito conocer la duración de la canción para ponerlo en un TextView

Comment: Hola Ruben. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Creo que una pregunta de este estilo, sí bien es totalmente válida, podría dar un poco más de información a quien quiera ayudarte (ayudanos a ayudarte). Para alguien que no está en tu lugar, la pregunta da muy poco contexto. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de esto, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar la clase [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever) y tener algo así:

```
public void getMetaDataSong(String song) { //song: ruta del archivo de audio
    MediaMetadataRetriever mdr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    long durationMs; //Milisegundos
    String titulo = null;
    String artista = null;
    try {
        mdr.setDataSource(song);
        titulo = mdr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
        artista = mdr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
        durationMs = Long.parseLong(mdr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));                   
        mdr.release();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Bien gracias lo probaré